# TouchesEnded event

Tags: objective-c, ios

I have a custom view that subclasses UIView. It has a touchesEnded event, however it does not show up in Interface Builder (under Events). I want to some how get that method into my View Controller so a method fires whenever the touchesEnded fires. I'm considering using target Action, however,

The code below doesn't work because forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchesEnded doesn't exist. So I don't know how I can get the touchesEnded method from my class that subclasses UIView.

```
    [customView addTarget:self action:@selector(actionWithUIControlEvent:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just let your view controller handling the event message. Implement the `touchesEnded:withEvent:` method in it, and call the second.

Comment: Could you please clarify. Thanks

Comment: `UIViewController` is a `UIResponder` subclass, hence your custom one is too. You could easily let it handle the event. Check this [doc](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIResponder_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UIResponder). Then you can either directly operate in the event handling method, or send a message to `self`, which is your custom VC.

Comment: Well the touchesEnded method is firing in the Custom View which subclasses UIView. In the xib file, which my ViewController is the owner, I have two subviews of a standard, main UIView. So I can't put the touchesended in my viewcontroller as you say, because it'll pick up events from all the subviews. I'm trying to get access to the custom view's (AFOpenFlowView) touchesEnded method. I want to set it up similar to connecting an IBAction to an event in a view. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Nevermind, I implemented some delegate protocols. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

From your view controller, you should be able create a `UITapGestureRecognizer` on your custom view. You can check the state of the recognizer to see if you're receiving the message on touches ended: `UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded`.