# Why isn't my navigation bar controller handling the touchesEnded event on my navigation bar view?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, touch-event

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6727043/touchesended-event) came closest to describing my problem, but I'm missing something in the general process and the answer eventually goes into "Never mind, I figured out a different solution that isn't described".

In my case, I've got an XIB with a navigation bar and its controller.  For the class fields, I've filled in my custom class names.  Here's a screenshot showing the XIB, because I think this should be a relatively simple and straightforward setup...

[image: Navigation bar and its controller.]

What I want (like in link at the beginning) is for the touchesEnded event to fire so that I can do something.  This works for the "view"; I can programmatically write in the event, set a breakpoint, and see that breakpoint get hit.  However, my higher-level goal is to push a new view onto the app at that point -- something that I shouldn't do in the view's functionality, and which I can't do anyway because my view doesn't have access to the navigation controller (unless I do some trickery to retrieve the controller, but I want to do this cleanly).

Even though it works programmatically for the view, the touchesEnded event does not get hit for the navigation view's controller.  I set it to the delegate, as shown in the image below, which I'm suspecting is perhaps only a part of what I need to do.

[image: I set the delegate of the Navigation Bar "view" to be the navigation controller.]

So now that I've set the delegate, and have seen that the touchesEnded event is being hit by the view, why isn't my navigation bar view controller picking up on the touchesEnded event?  Am I mistaken and should instead be figuring out how to push a new view from the navigation bar's view, since I've seen that THAT touchesEnded event is being hit?  It just seems like something I should be handling in the navigation bar view's controller, but I can't get that controller's touchesEnded event hit.

Thanks!

Comment: I think you don't understand how navigation controllers work. Why don't you explain what you're trying to achieve? If you want to push to a new controller, that's usually done from a button (or table cell) in the view that belongs to the navigation controller. You don't do anything directly with the navigation bar, the controller handles that.

Comment: That could very well be the case.  I want to make it so when I tap a part of the navigation bar, a new view is pushed -- much like the about button in this image might cause (http://cdn2.raywenderlich.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/09/Screen-Shot-2012-09-18-at-12.15.02-AM-2.png).  Instead of showing a button, though, I want it to be flush with the background image and am using the navigation bar's touch events for getting a start on this implementation.  Can I not do the same thing that the button does from the navigation bar itself?

Comment: I'm not sure whether it can be done that way (probably, but I've never done it like that). What is the context of why you're pushing to the new view?

Comment: Well, we want to show a person's picture in the navigation bar.  When you tap your picture, there's information about you as a user.  That's why the design called for that, but if the answer is that "This isn't possible" or "There are really fundamental architectural reasons as to why XCode should not be used this way, use the right-side button instead", I'm open to understanding and relaying that.  A circle with a person's picture in it probably won't resolve well to a button, which is why I was exploring simply building off the bar itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear from your post, but it looks like you're adding a navigation bar to your app explicitly, is that true? If your controller is embedded in a navigation controller, then there's no need to do that. You can add a view to the navigation bar, and add a UIImage view as a subview. If you set user interaction to be on, and add a tap gesture recognizer to the image view, you should be able to get the effect you want.

Comment: I'm a bit glad it's not clear from my post, because it's also not clear to me, heh!  This is pre-existing code that I'm modifying to get the desired design, if possible.  Thanks to you pointing out that this information is (correctly) missing, I know that I'll need to look at where the navigation bar is added (or not) and possibly re-do it from scratch to have the controller embedded. If you know of a tutorial that would show me better how to do this than my explorations will, please feel free to share it!

Answer (score 1):

Then you have to override UINavigationBar, and override becomeFirstResponder, returning YES.

Comment: Thanks, I'll start looking into that method.

Comment: So my navigation bar view class is indeed a child of UINavigationBar, so overriding becomeFirstResponder to return YES was pretty simple.  Even with this change, however, the set delegate is not hitting touchesEnded upon taps/clicks/etc.

Comment: Don't set any delegate, just override touchesEnded:withEvent in the same class.

Comment: Interesting, so this essentially executes that functionality in the view instead of the controller?  In theory, I know that will work, but I want to make sure that if I blend the view/controller in the MVC design pattern that I isolate this incident and it doesn't carry over past this single method.

Comment: This change is resulting in touchesEnded being called in the UINavigationBar-deriving class, but that was already happening.  How does this now being a firstResponder let me manage the views pushed onto/popped out of the navigation controller?  Also: it looks like overriding touchesEnded makes it so that Back buttons no longer work.  I don't think doing this functionality in the view is going to fly, for that reason...

Comment: Call touchesEnded:withEvent also on super, that's why you don't trigger the button action, the events must be propagated through all classes. As for the first question I haven't understood it well: what do you want to manage exactly?

Comment: A UINavigationController (http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) is what manages the views shown on the screen.  It's usually a ViewController that has this, but overriding touchesEnded in the view (the child of UINavigationBar as you've described) means that I don't have access to this.  Since the touch is supposed to push a view onto the screen, I would need access to that navigation controller.  How do I access it from the view, which is where your solution is implemented (as opposed to a controller)?